# Searching for a tweet using Twitter4j

Tags: java, search, twitter, twitter4j

I have a problem using Twitter4j. I need to recover a tweet using its id but when I search, the result it's always [ ]. Here is the code:

```
        ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
                .setOAuthConsumerKey("XXXXXXXXX")
                .setOAuthConsumerSecret("XXXXXXXX")
                .setOAuthAccessToken("XXXXXXXX")
                .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("XXXXXXXXX");

        TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());

        twitter = tf.getInstance();

        Query searchTweet = new Query("id:twitter4j " + Long.parseLong("427552735219965952"));
        QueryResult resultSearchTweet = twitter.search(searchTweet);
        System.out.println("Value: " + resultSearchTweet);
        System.out.println("Tweets: " + resultSearchTweet.getTweets());
        System.out.println("Tweets size: " + resultSearchTweet.getTweets().size());
```

And here is the exit:

```
Value: QueryResultJSONImpl{sinceId=0, maxId=603858195988131841, refreshUrl='?since_id=603858195988131841&q=id%3Atwitter4j%20427552735219965952&include_entities=1', count=15, completedIn=0.028, query='id:twitter4j 427552735219965952', tweets=[]}
Tweets: []
Tweets size: 0
```

Two observations:

1)  I need to use search function because it has more rate limit than
      other functions.

2)  The tweet exists.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance and sorry for my english :).

Answer (score 0):

I just found a solution. I search the tweets that a certain user using an URL of the tweet then I access to the JSON and get what I want

Thank you very much :).

Comment: It would be nice if you added a snippet with your solution. And, if it worked, set this as the accepted answer.